# decode json in php

Tags: php, json, api

I'm using Google's currency calculation api. It returns json. I can get the URL contents into a string, but how can I parse this in php? I'm trying to return the "rhs" value.

```
    $string='{lhs: "1 Euro",rhs: "1.3067 U.S. dollars",error: "",icc: true}'; 
    $rhs=?????
    echo $rhs;
```

Comment: See [json_decode](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$string='{lhs: "1 Euro",rhs: "1.3067 U.S. dollars",error: "",icc: true}'; 
$json=json_decode($string);
echo $json->rhs;
```

http://us.php.net/json_decode

Answer (score 1):

`json_decode()` is what you would use.

```
$data = json_decode($string);
$rhs = $data->rhs;
```

Answer (score 0):

use `json_decode`

```
$rhs = json_decode($string);
// $rhs is an object now.
```

Comment: No, without passing TRUE as the second parameter, $rhs is an object now, not a string.

Answer (score 0):

There's not much to it:

```
$obj = json_decode($string);
$rhs = $obj->rhs;
```

Answer (score -1):

Use PHP's [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function:

```
$string      = '{lhs: "1 Euro",rhs: "1.3067 U.S. dollars",error: "",icc: true}';
$json_object = json_decode($string);
$rhs         = $json_array->rhs;

echo $rhs;
```

Comment: Similar to Indranil, using `json_decode()` without the second parameter being true means that `$json_array` is of type Object, not of type Array. You must access members of an Object with `->` syntax.